# Fourier transform of $f'(t)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

The Fourier transform of f′(t) is :

$$\hat{f'}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f'(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt = f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\bigg\vert_{-\infty}^{+\infty} +i\omega\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt = i\omega\hat{f}(\omega)$$

So $f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\bigg |_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ must be zero but I don't understand how... ?

Comment: conditions for $f$ ?

Comment: You need someone conditions for $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary that $f$ has compact support in $\mathbb{R}$, so if $f$ has compact support $K\subset \mathbb{R}$, then

$$f(t)e^{-iwt}\bigg\vert^{+\infty}_{-\infty}=0,$$

cause $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash K.$

Comment: No it isn't necessary. For instance, $e^{-t^2}$ has a Fourier transform.

Comment: One could even lift this property to [Schwartz distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform).

Comment: @YvesDaoust this function belongs to Schwarz space

Comment: @Maman: yep, and has unbounded support.